# merge 2 json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

So I have 2 json which has one same parameter.
based on this one parameter I want to merge these two json into single json.

```
json 1 = [{"serverid":65,"name":"Apple"},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac"}]

json 2 = [{"serverid":98,"count":9},{"serverid":65,"count":2}]

resultant json = [{"serverid":65,"name":"Apple","count":2},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac","count":9}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Object.assign()

```
const a = [{"serverid":65,"name":"Apple"},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac"}];
const b = [{"serverid":65,"count":2},{"serverid":98,"count":9}];
const c = a.map((obj, index) => Object.assign(obj, b[index]));
```

to learn more about [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const a = [{"serverid":65,"name":"Apple"},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac"}];
const b = [{"serverid":65,"count":2},{"serverid":98,"count":9}];
const c = a.map((obj, index) => Object.assign(obj, b[index]));

console.log(c)
```

Comment: what if the order of json order is not same.      json 1 = [{"serverid":65,"name":"Apple"},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac"}]
json 2 = [{"serverid":98,"count":9},{"serverid":65,"count":2}].      So I have to search for serversid first and then push data according the desired server id.                     resultant json = [{"serverid":65,"name":"Apple","count":2},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac","count":9}]

Answer (score 2):

A clean way of doing is is using the object spread operator. What the object spread operator does in an object literal is copying all old values into the newly created object.

### Example:

```js
const json1 = [{"serverid": 65,"name": "Apple"},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac"}]

const json2 = [{"serverid":65,"count":2},{"serverid":98,"count":9}]

const newArr = []

for (let i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
   const obj = {
    ...json1[i],
    ...json2[i]
  }
   
   newArr.push(obj);  

}
   
 console.log(newArr)
```

**Caveat:**

This is relatively new syntax `ES7` and you have to transpile the code (using e.g. babel) in order to have full browser compatibility.